# How to connect to sql server 2008 via an IP address using pyodbc in Python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am able to connect to server with mssql management studio but not able to connect using python I think  some problem in connection string please help below is string I am using.

```
import pyodbc as p

connStr = ( r'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=ip; Network=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=' + database + ';User ID=' + id +';Password=' + pass1 +';Trusted_Connection=True' +';')

conn = p.connect(connStr)
```

error is like below

```
 conn = p.connect(connStr)
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sock
ets]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnectW); [01000
] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
 (10060); [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string a
ttribute (0)')
```

Comment: Has SQL server been configured to listen on TCP sockets? By default it doesn't. You'd have to go into the Configuration Manager to check

Comment: thanks for ur reply Marc.. yes it is listening on port 1433..which is i am using in ip

Comment: is anyone connected using ip to sql server 2008..i found very few documentation about this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lots of trial and error this string ended up working:

```
connStr = ('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=ip;port=port;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Database=TEST;uid=id;pwd=pass;')
```

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two or three SQL Server drivers written and distrubuted by Microsoft: one referred to as "SQL Server" and the other as "SQL Native Client" and "SQL Server Native Client 10.0}".

> **DRIVER**={SQL
>   Server};SERVER=cloak;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password
>
> **DRIVER**={SQL Native
>   Client};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password
>
> **DRIVER**={SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password

The "SQL Server" one works for all versions of SQL Server, but only enables features and data types supported by SQL Server 2000, regardless of your actual server version.

For SQL Server 2005 installations, use "SQL Native Client" to enable 2005 features and types. Note that this version is not provided in all SQL Server 2008 installations!

Finally, you need "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" for SQL Server 2008 features and types.